# Accessing Ajax/Dynamic checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

How do I check all checkboxes which have been returned as part of an AJAX request?

I have a page which displays email message summaries (think gmail/yahoo/etc... inbox). Each summary has a checkbox associated with it so that my user could do any number of things with the message. At the top and bottom of the list is a "check all" option. I know how to bind delegate functions to the dynamic checkboxes, but I can't seemt to find any way to give my "Check All" button the ability to manipulate these dynamic elements. Example:

```
//get the list of messages
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetMessages.asmx/GetMessagePreview",
    data: "{'FolderID': '5'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
       //code here to create a checkbox row (checkbox, message title, etc...)
       var cbRow = '<input type="checkbox" class="msg_check" ...etc... />'
       //code here to insert to a div or other container   
}
 });

$("#selectAllButton").click( function(){
   ????? This is the blank I need filled in...
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy:

```
$("#selectAllButton").click( function(){
    if (this.checked)
        $('.msg_check').attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
        $('.msg_check').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Edited: if you want to insert item in the same condition, as all other items (all checked/unchecked), do next:

```
// ...
var checked = $("#selectAllButton").is(':checked');
var cbRow = $('<input type="checkbox" class="msg_check" />');
cbRow.appendTo(list);
var checkbox = cbRow.find('.msg_check');

if (checked)
    checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
else
    checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
// ...
```

Comment: This won't work because the elements I'm trying to access are not in the DOM, therefore I can't just treat them like normal elements.

Comment: But why don't you insert them into DOM first?

Comment: I am doing an append() when I create the HTML and add it to my container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the elements that come with the ajax call to *inherit* the current state of the `#selectAll` checkbox, then you need to read that and apply it as you create the new elements.

so

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetMessages.asmx/GetMessagePreview",
    data: "{'FolderID': '5'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

       var currentState = $("#selectAllButton").is(':checked') ? 'checked' : '';

       //code here to create a checkbox row (checkbox, message title, etc...)
       var cbRow = '<input type="checkbox" class="msg_check" '+ currentState +' />';
       //code here to insert to a div or other container   
}
 });

$("#selectAllButton").click( function(){
   // the way you normally select your elements..
   $('.msg_check')....
});
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but placement of the click event handler had everything to do with my problem. I am constructing my page using ascx (ASP.NET controls). I had the logic to do the select/deselect all in the control containing the message list container... When I moved it to the main ASPX page's header tag, all is well... 

Thank you both for your comments and responses. I love this site because of people like you. :)

Comment: @jobo :) glad you got it sorted out :)